# Increasing decimal number of percentage in dash plotly pie chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, pie-chart, plotly-dash

I am trying to plot a pie chart using dash and plotly but the problem is that when I plot it.
It rounds off the percentage to 100% as it should be 99.97%.

it shows 100% but it must show something like 99.97%

```
dcc.Graph(
        id="piechart_2",
        figure={
            "data": [
                {
                    "labels": string_request,
                    "values": val_request,
                    "type": "pie",
                    "marker": {"line": {"color": "red", "width": 1}},
                }
            ],
            "layout": {

                "height":500,
                "width":500
            },
            'legend': {'x': 0, 'y': 1},

        },
    ),
```

[image: it shows 100% but it must show something like 99.97%]

Comment: Have you tried having the percentage as a real or float variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own percentages and then show them by using `textinfo`:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

import plotly.graph_objects as go

labels = ['bind','rpz']
values = [99.9628, 0.0372]
text = [str(i)+'%' for i in values]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels,
                             values=values,
                             text=text,
                             textinfo='text')])

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(figure=fig)])

app.run_server(debug=True,
               use_reloader=False)
```

and you get:

[image]